# Como fazer um arquivo python executar comandos no cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

Por exemplo:

```
netsh wlan show profile
```

Esse comando do **cmd** mostra as redes wifi já conectadas, pelo menos uma vez ao meu notebook!

Como posso executar esse comando usando o python 3?

Comment: Ola @rafael, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Editei sua pergunta se você achar que eu alterei o sentido, ou por qualquer outro motivo você pode reverter a edição acessando os [revisions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/387389/revisions) =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta usar a biblioteca `os`

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import os
os.system('netsh wlan show profile')
```

Comment: Obrigado cara! ainda sou novo na programação!!